# Spring Cloud Config Server - Connect to Github account with 2FA

Tags: spring, github, spring-cloud

I'm trying to create a Spring Cloud Config Server to retrieve configuration files from a private GitHub repository. My GitHub account has 2 Factor Authentication activated so I wasn't expecting the below configuration to work, which it didn't but I can't find any documentation to suggest what I need to do in order to make it work.

What configuration do I need to set that will allow the connection to work?

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/DanBonehill/photo-app-config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=USERNAME
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=PASSWORD
```

Error

`org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/DanBonehill/photo-app-config: not authorized`

Answer (score 4):

What you could try and do (have not tested this), is create a personal access token from the Github console.

Then configure

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=<yourusername>
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=<yourtoken>
```

Comment: This actually works !! For future who wants to try this method

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `username` and `password` you should use an `ssh` key, the [official documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_git_ssh_configuration_using_properties) can guide you through it!

Comment: Thanks, I changed the uri to the ssh one but it still wasn't working. I realised it was because my private key wasn't in the right format. Once I corrected this it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication using a password to Git is deprecated and will soon no longer work. Visit https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.

Answer (score 0):

you solve this in 2 minutes, this problem is because at August 13, 2021 the github update the login form, to solve this.

**1)** login in your gitHub folow this path: *Settings >  Developer settings > Personal access tokens > Generate new token*

**2)** Now set a long time to expiration token, check the "repo" to allow access repository with this token, and Generate token.

**3)** Now skill your github password because this token created  is your new password, replace this at all application, server, terminal that need to access github.

**4)** Now configure your spring configuration server, this is a content of file "application.properties" of spring configuration server at path /src/main/resources/application.properties.

> spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri= [https://github.com/"username"/"repository"](https://github.com/%22username%22/%22repository%22)  //your githur repository
> spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths= myFilesFolder  /if your files is into some folder
> spring.cloud.config.server.git.username= testUsername // your username
> spring.cloud.config.server.git.password= gti_FdsweecSoUSHPsdfw  //Here is your new token created